# CompletableFuture Loop API Calls and Map to Object

Tags: java, completable-future

I am having some trouble while experimenting with CompletableFutures

What I am trying to do is break up a list of Objects into partitions (smaller Object lists) using Google Guava, then asynchronously spin up new threads to call an API with each subset list of Objects. I want to wait until all these futures are completed, then combine these results into a single return object. Here is a non-working example of what I'm trying to do. This example does not compile due to this line:

```
return CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()])).join();
```

The method expects a Position return type but CompletableFuture.allOf() returns Void. However, I thought that adding .join() should give me the desired Position return type. This is where I am stuck.

```
public Position fetchPosition(List<UnitDTO> unitDTOList) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<List<UnitDTO>> subsets = Lists.partition(unitDTOList, 2);
    List<CompletableFuture<Position>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();

    for(List<UnitDTO> subset : subsets){
      completableFutures.add(getPositionDetailsAsync(subset));
    }
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()])).join();
}

public CompletableFuture<Position> getPositionDetailsAsync(List<UnitDTO> unitDTOList){
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      Position position = new Position();
      try {
        position = myApiClient.getPosition();
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return position;
    });
```

}

I know I'm not giving much to work with here but basically I am not sure if this is the proper approach or if I am on the right track. Hopefully my issue makes sense. I'm happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: You note that your example is non-working, which is good.  What would be better is if you described what parts were not working.  Does the example compile, does it not work asynchronously, where exactly are the deficiencies in the code you've provided?  To this, some people might not immediately recognize that you are using guava, and may think that Lists.partition is not compiling because it is not standard Java.

Comment: @wrestang thanks, I have edited the post for (hopefully) more clarity. Pointing out the use of guava as well as the compilation error due to return type

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with a paraller stream instead of Guava and completable futures?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think of how you want to reduce the list of `Position` values into a single `Position`. Then you can use [Stream.reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) to convert a `Stream<CompletableFuture<Position>>` into a `CompletableFuture<Position>` by lifting that reduction function into the stream:

```
static <T> CompletableFuture<T> reduce(
        Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> futures,
        T identity,
        BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
{
    return futures.reduce(
        completedFuture(identity),
        (f1, f2) ->
            f1.thenCompose(s1 ->
            f2.thenApply(s2 ->
                accumulator.apply(s1, s2))));
}
```

For example, to concatenate some strings wrapped in `CompletableFuture`s you would do

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = Stream.of(
    completedFuture("A"),
    completedFuture("mouse"),
    completedFuture("took"),
    completedFuture("a"),
    completedFuture("stroll"));

System.out.println(
    reduce(futures, "", (s1, s2) -> s1 + " " + s2).get());
```

Which prints "A mouse took a stroll"